# C++ Printing out function

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a total random number between a set of integers but I have no idea how to print the result:

```
 mt19937 mt_rand(time(0));
 mt19937::result_type seed = time(0);
 auto dice_rand = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1,6),
                           mt19937(seed));
 std::function<int()> dice3 = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1,6),
                                        mt19937(seed));

    int x = dice3;
    qDebug()<< "Result" << x ;
```

I keep getting errors because of type INT. I am new to C++ and QT. How can I print out an INT? I have tried printing dice_rand, then I tried to convert it to a std::fucntion but I still can't seem to print it.

Comment: Without a [complete and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or even the exact errors you are getting, this is hard to answer... but I seriously doubt the *printing* is your problem.

Comment: "keep getting errors" - That's like going to a mechanic with your car which has problems with the windshield wiper, and all you're saying is "oh, I have problems with the car". Which is true, but not really helpful... Show the unaltered error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dice3` is a function. You should call it.

```
int x = dice3();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry its been a long day.

Comment: `dice3` is an `std::function`. Not a function.

Comment: @AndreasVennström true, but the solution stays the same right?

Comment: You're right.
For more information check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @hat_to_the_back if this fixed your problem, could you mark this as the answer?

Comment: @Timo, you should upvote the question, cause I think it's valid. (I already did once).

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz I think the question could have been formulated better, e.g. provide the actual error message.

Comment: @Timo, agreed. I just don't think it deserves negative votes.